# Sending an email using MailKit in Xamarin Studio on Mac C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio, mailkit

I am trying to write an android app in Xamarin Studio for Mac that will send an email once a button is clicked. I have the button and the app will run when the button is clicked if I don't try to send the email. However, when I add the MailKit commands shown in the code below, the app crashes every time. Any help would be appreciated!

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Net;
using MimeKit;
using MailKit; 
using MailKit.Net.Smtp; 

namespace MyProject
{
    [Activity (Label = "MyProject", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it


        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnOne); 
        TextView text = (TextView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1); 
        button.Click += delegate {




            var message = new MimeMessage ();
            message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("User Name", "username@gmail.com"));
            message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Other User", "otheruser@gmail.com"));
            message.Subject = "Does it work???";


            var builder = new BodyBuilder (); 

            builder.TextBody = "Hello, world!"; 
            message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody (); 

            using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {

                client.Connect ("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true); 

                client.Authenticate ("username", "password"); 

                client.Send (message); 
                client.Disconnect (true); 

            }

        };

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where (which specific line) causes the crash?  What does the log/exception/stacktrace say?  Does it crash when you run it, or only when you click the button?

Comment: It crashes after I press the button. I tested it one line at a time and it seems to crash when trying to connect to the smtp client.

Comment: is it crashing in the simulator, the device, or both?  Do you have internet permissions enabled in your manifest?  Do you have a firewall or something blocking that port?  Can you trap the exception in a try-catch to see details of the exception?